# Nautilus default .desktop file not right

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, file-management, nautilus

I need some help with the GNOME Nautilus file manager.

The default `.desktop` file situated is `/usr/share/applications` has been deleted and replaced with my own one (no back up).

I was hoping to recover it's content. The only options I modified were `TryExec` and `Exec`:

```
TryExec=nautilus-autorun-software, Exec=nautilus-autorun-software %u
```

I've Googled it and searched in the docs but no luck!

Please help me out with this one, and thanks in advance.

Comment: apt install --reinstall nautilus

Comment: i have already tried it and it's not working as expected i dont know why !!